# Device telemetry: enum as schema.. How to use value/display value

Tags: azure-iot-central

We have a device template with an interface definition that contains a capability with Enum as schema... with possible values 0, 1, 2. For each of the values, I've defined a display name as shown in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo0wl.png).

I've expected this display names would show in the Dashboard when showing "Last known value", however it still shows the values (0, 1, 2).

Am I missing anything here? Where/how are these enum display names used? How do we use them on the dashboards?

Answer (score 0):

The following screen snippet shows an example of the mapping enum values of the telemetry state in the *IoT Central preview* app:

- *Last known Value*, where is displayed **raw value** (no mapping) from the telemetry data
- *State History*, where is used mapping to the DisplayName during the time range. Note, that if the mapping is out of the enum values, the DisplayName is empty.
- *Pie chart*, where is displayed the counts of the same values during the time range

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "State history" option. So there is no possibility of showing Display values as last known values as it seems...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked my configuration and I work in the Interface with the Enum schema too.

[IoT Central Interface + Schema view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eOlG.png)

But I also have set on the Customization section for the Device Template the Semantic type **State**.

[IoT Central - Customize Interface value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8A9G.png)

In this Case I got the "Last known value" graph with the text.

The **State History** I got only when the capability type is set to **State** by the semantic type allready ;)

[IoT Central - Capability type "Sate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWlER.png)